# ExpressJS Timestamp Timezone

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 applications running on the same machine, inserting to the same database.

The other in PHP, is set to another timezone. Not the machine time.

The nodeJS express application is also inserting into the database, but it is inserting with the current time of the machine, I want to change it like the PHP application.

But how do I do that with Express? Note: I am using the BookshelfJS ORM.

Comment: Why don't you synchronize both servers using NTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify timezone in the environment:

```
process.env.TZ="EST"
```

Comment: added this to the very top of my ExpressJS app.js :)